# From Skateboarding to Snowboarding?

Tags: technique, snowboarding, skateboarding

I've been Skateboarding for at least 5 years on and off now and I've started to gain an interest in snowboarding too. I was wondering, I'm aware of all the differences between skating and snowboarding but is there anything I can take from my skating and apply to Snowboarding that will give me a head start. I ask because I don't want to end up falling on my face on a downhill snow slope...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been in the same position as you and hope I can shed some light on the subject:
I found that it wasn't super difficult to transfer over, but the major thing was the idea of bindings and boots. This is a major difference, as now your feet are attached to the board which will change you balance and how comfortable you are on a board. The technique is pretty similar with leaning and balance etc. Watch some videos online to decide what footing you are. If you are a proficient skater, you should have no real issue transferring over to snowboarding.

I would advise you to start on the short hills to promote safety and learn the ropes, and in all seriousness WEAR A HELMET! I know it isn't cool, but neither is having your brain scrambled! I received a severe concussion from snowboarding and it altered my life mentally and physically. I never wore a helmet when I would skate, but I was glad to have it that day on the slopes. 
Keep it real and enjoy the slopes this season!